# Aligning text in wrapped `column` output when newlines are present

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```bash
docs=(
  "    cmd1||Run cmd1."
  "    cmd3||Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text."
  $'    cmd2|[N]|Do something with N.\nA new line.\nAnother line'
)

column -t \
  --separator "|" \
  --output-width 60 \
  --table-noheadings \
  --table-wrap C3 \
  --table-columns C1,C2,C3 < <(printf "%s\n" "${docs[@]}")

#     cmd1               Run cmd1.
#     cmd3               Long text Long text Long text Long text L
#                        ong text Long text.
#     cmd2          [N]  Do something with N.
# A new line.
# Another line

# Expected:
#     cmd1               Run cmd1.
#     cmd3               Long text Long text Long text Long text L
#                        ong text Long text.
#     cmd2          [N]  Do something with N.
#                        A new line.
#                        Another line
```

I'd like to maintain newlines in each cell for clarity, but there doesn't seem to be a flag for this purpose (for context, column 3 is extracted from function comments, etc., so I don't want every new line mushed in together). Is there a robust method to align each cell's content as in the expected output?
As a workaround, I was thinking of somehow calculating C1 and C2 widths and prepending spaces with `sed`, but feels cumbersome and I don't see how that could be done.

**EDIT**: The `docs` array and each doc's contents are dynamically generated every time.

**column from util-linux 2.36.2**

Comment: Replace the newlines in the array elements with spaces before passing them to `column`?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `printf "%s\n" "${docs[@]//$'\n'/ }"` I believe.

Comment: @Cyrus It's there already.

Comment: @Shawn that's exactly my workaround now, but in reality I'd like to maintain the exact format (for context, column 3 is extracted from function comments, etc.) So preferably I don't want everything mushed in together

Comment: Why not just format it the way you like in a *heredoc*?

Comment: The `docs` array is dynamically generated every time, I forgot to explicitly mention it

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, the simplest and most robust solution seems to be just splitting the last column contents by newlines and constructing new rows with empty cells:

```bash
docs=(
  "    cmd1||Run cmd1."
  "    cmd3||Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text."
  $'    cmd2|[N]|Do something with N.'
  $'    ||A very very very very very very very very long line.'
  $'    ||Another line'
)

column -t \
  --separator "|" \
  --output-width 60 \
  --table-noheadings \
  --table-wrap C3 \
  --table-columns C1,C2,C3 < <(printf "%s\n" "${docs[@]}")

# cmd1       Run cmd1.
# cmd3       Long text Long text Long text Long text Long 
#            text Long text.
# cmd2  [N]  Do something with N.
#            A very very very very very very very very lon
#            g line.
#            Another line
```